# Image formation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics, geometric-optics

What is the real cause behind the formation of an image? It is explained as" when rays of light focus at a point image is formed." So here we have two events, one focusing of light and another formation of an image? Now my question is what is the intermediate phenomenon that converts focusing of light rays into the formation of an image?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57234/2451

Comment: We don't have two events. The image *is* the convergence of rays. That is to says that the noun "image" means the appearance of a solid object whether the luminous projection of a real image, or the apparent origin of diverging rays in a virtual image.

Comment: Please don't re-post. Address the issues with the original.

Comment: It occurs to me that much of the language and the diagrams used in standard treatments of the topic encourages this kind of confusion (that is that we draw *another* object at the point where *"the image forms"* as if the image were something other than the result of the light). Something to think about for the next time *I* teach the subject.